# Not correctly formatted hyperlink

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, markdown-rendering, formatting

There seems to be some problem with the handling of links after `<h1></h1>`. It wasn't there some months ago. The problem is here and on the main site (I've noticed because I opened an old answer of mine and the first thing I thought was that it had been defaced). The problem sees to exist if I have some links in the form `<h1></h1>[Text](http://link.com)` with the `<h1>` in the beginning of the line (??). So `x<h1>d</h1>[Text](http://link.com)` works correctly (??).

Example text 1 Some text... [Correctly formatted hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com)

## Example text 2

Some text... [Not correctly formatted hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com)

x

## Example text 3

Some text... [Correctly formatted hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: The CommonMark parser is picky when you mix regular html and mark down. An extra line or space does change the render behavior.

Comment: @rene So [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348746/were-switching-to-commonmark)... Ok... My response is in the 4% that isn't rendered correctly... I haven't posted a link to the problematic post I have because I didn't want to advertise it.

Comment: Yeah, I have done some work on finding the 4% troublesome posts but it is tricky to find them without having a ton of false positives.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not mix html and markdown.

This is maybe not what you hoped for but instead of trying to find / fix these mishaps with code / parsing I think it is better to have some recipes to fix the posts that are still out in the wild. A capable human is probably better equipped to deal with all the quirks between the client and server side implementation and the [CommonMark specification](https://commonmark.org/).

Here is the recipe to fix the case you've found:

Example text 1 Some text... [Correctly formatted hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com)

## Example text 2

Some text... [Not correctly formatted hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com)

## Example text 3

Some text... [Correctly formatted hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com)

#### Markdown

```
Example text 1 Some text... [Correctly formatted hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com)

# Example text 2
Some text... [Not correctly formatted hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com)

# Example text 3
Some text... [Correctly formatted hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com)
```

---

#### Alternative

---

Example text 1 Some text... [Correctly formatted hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com)

## Example text 2

Some text... [Not correctly formatted hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com)

x

## Example text 3

Some text... [Correctly formatted hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com)

#### Markdown

```
Example text 1 Some text... [Correctly formatted hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com)

<h1>Example text 2</h1> Some text... <a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Not correctly formatted hyperlink</a>

x<h1>Example text 3</h1> Some text... [Correctly formatted hyperlink](https://stackoverflow.com)
```

Comment: Alternative tip: No matter whether you're using HTML, Markdown, or both, **always** add a blank line between formatting elements. This solves parser issues 98% of the time.