# Markdown broken on edit?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, markdown-rendering

I just made an edit on the following question:  [Is there a random number distribution that obeys Benford's Law?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14556451/5987).  The parts of the question that I didn't edit are displaying are just fine, but a link and word surrounded by backticks aren't - they display as if markdown wasn't working at all.  They are broken both in the edit preview and in the rendered output after the edit.

I can't even formulate a theory on what is going on.

Comment: It appears like this to me:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Wfq7.png. I am assuming this is what you wanted, as you say _"a link and word"_

Comment: @10Repsaysgetvaccinated no, that was part of the older post that didn't change.  The broken bits are closer to the end.

Comment: @10Rep He was talking about a sentence further down in the post, the one starting with "Using John Dvorak's answer", which rendered with the literal `[]()` instead of as a link.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using the HTML `<hr>` tag. The Markdown parser requires that HTML tags like that be followed with a blank line. When the post is edited to add a blank line after the `<hr>` tag, the inline link Markdown syntax is parsed and rendered just fine. (I tried to demo this, but my subsequent edit designed to show an even better way merged with the original edit showing a minimal fix, so you won't actually see the evidence of it in the revision history.)

Note that [it's preferable to avoid mixing HTML and Markdown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404438). The Markdown syntax for a horizontal line is just three (or more) dashes, on a new line by themselves:

```
---
```

Editing the post with that also allows the inline link Markdown syntax to be rendered correctly.

The reason that this would have changed simply by trying to edit it now is because the final rendered result (generated from the Markdown intermediate) is saved and cached at the time of submission. When you first created that post, Stack Overflow was using a different Markdown implementation than we are now. With [the migration to CommonMark](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/398481/stack-overflow-is-migrating-to-commonmark-on-saturday-june-20-2020?r=SearchResults&s=20%7C0.0000), some of the rules have changed, and when you edit now, you're subjected to the new (current) rules.

Comment: Thank you, your edit appears to have fixed it and your explanation makes perfect sense.